# Concatenate multiple input functial API CNN models in keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I have 8 CNN models model1, model2, model3, model4, model5, model6, model7, model8 each with conv2d, activation, maxpooling, dropout layers. I want to concatenate the output of them, compile and fit, my model as the figure bellow:

[image]

I'm confusing in concatenation,merging and fitting. my python code is bellow:

```
out1 = Flatten()(model1)
out2 = Flatten()(model2)
out3 = Flatten()(model3)
out4 = Flatten()(model4)
out5 = Flatten()(model5)
out6 = Flatten()(model6)
out7 = Flatten()(model7)
out8 = Flatten()(model8)
merge = Concatenate([out1, out2, out3, out4, out5, out6, out7, out8])

final_out = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(merge) 

final_model = Model([out1, out2, out3, out4, out5, out6, out7, out8], final_out)

final_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentr", optimizer= opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

final_model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),validation_data=(testX, testY),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Layer dense_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor
```

What is the problem? how can I concatenate, compile, train? can anyone please help me, any information will be helpful.